# Adding a New Event manually in kalCalender

Tags: iphone, ios, calendar

I just want to add a event manually in my prog from using the kalcalender from add button. But basically i have no idea of that.

https://github.com/klazuka/Kal

I try to understand from the nativecal, But i cant get it.

thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Hopefully someone else can help you on your question, but I assume you've already considered using Apple's [EKEventEditViewController](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#DOCUMENTATION/EventKitUI/Reference/EKEventEditViewControllerClassRef/Reference/Reference.html). The [Event Kit Programming Guide](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#DOCUMENTATION/DataManagement/Conceptual/EventKitProgGuide/Introduction/Introduction.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40009765) explains is pretty well. I add calendar events in the user's calendar incredibly easily with that, but perhaps you're trying to do something that I don't understand.